# Should we merge coffee-culture and tradition tags?

Tags: discussion

I think the question is straightforward. Are they synonyms or do are there nuances? I think they could be declared as synonyms.

Comment: I can see both sides to this, so I'm unsure. On the one hand, tradition could clearly delineate itself as questions on historic coffee-culture. But on the other hand, do we really have enough questions tagged in this way that separating them makes it easier to find what you want? Or do we risk just fragmenting the fairly similar questions?

Comment: I opt to generate a synonym as tradition only have three questions. In the future, maybe the synonym could be undefined if tradition seem to take more attention?